# why is the output of my program 0.000000 when it should be the value i entered when prompted. below is the code

Tags: c, floating-point, scanf, format-specifiers

I am trying to execute this code. but the number variable isn't storing the value I input,what could be posssible explanations of this behaviour.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    float number;
    
    printf("enter a value\n");
    scanf("%5.3f",&number);
    printf("u entered : %f",number);

    return 0;
}
```

and below is sample of its execution

```
enter a value
78.467  
u entered : 0.000000
```

Why isn't number storing the value 78.467

Comment: Remove the "5.3" from the "%f" token of the scanf format string... One formats output, but floating point is... dicey... Take what you get...

Comment: Compile with warnings: `scanf("%5.3f",&number);` -> _unknown conversion type character ‘.’ in format_. You want `scanf("%f",&number);` and then `printf("u entered : %5.3f",number);`

Comment: One further thing... You cannot control the number entered, so someone might enter "23.4567" when you must only use 2 decimal places of precision... If you go one to calculate with 'number' best to `round()` it to what you want before using it... Floating point can be a challenge...

Answer (score 0):

- `%5.3f` is not a valid `scanf` format. It should be `%f`.
- You also do not check that `scanf` succeeds. Always do.

Example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    float number;

    puts("enter a value");
    if(scanf("%f", &number) == 1) {          // check that it succeeds
        printf("u entered : %5.3f", number); // in printf %5.3f is ok
    } else {
        puts("Erroneous input");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`"%5.3f"` in `scanf("%5.3f",&number);` is an invalid format so the result is undefined behavior (UB).

The `"5"` is OK.  It limits the number of characters read in the conversion to at most 5.

`".3"` is not part of a valid conversion specification.

Save time, enable all warnings. [@David Ranieri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73173380/why-is-the-output-of-my-program-0-000000-when-it-should-be-the-value-i-entered-w/73175220#comment129232215_73173380)

```
// scanf("%5.3f",&number);
if (scanf("%f",&number) != 1) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Non-numeric input\n");
  return -1; 
}
```